# Is the Salesforce Lightning External Services (Beta) free

Tags: integration, webservices, lightning-connect

Does the External Services functionality cost extra or is it an included feature?

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_external_services.htm

Comment: 99% of times Unless it's mentioned available at extra cost it's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External Services became [generally available](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_ext_services.htm) in Summer '18, and has the following availability:

```
Available in: Lightning Experience
Available in: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions
```

**References**

- [External Services: Generally Available with Enhancements | Salesforce Summer '18 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_ext_services.htm)
- [External Services | Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_services.htm&type=5)
- [Connecting to Swagger-backed APIs with Clicks or Code | Developer Force Blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/04/connecting-to-swagger-backed-apis-with-clicks-or-code.html)